Select statement to get the properties from distantly related tables
I have an inventory table INV. I also have a particular ID MyID from another object.
I want a select statement that gets me a few columns from INV and one column from a table that is several steps away.
I have table B, from which we want all sID values where 'bID' = MyID and SomeOtherColumn = 1.
If we take those results and then look at another table, S, we will find each sID lines up with exactly one ID from the INV table. So now we have our one-to-one relationship for each INV row to one sID.
Then I have table T. Each row in T has a sID, a tID, and a Date. Each combination of these 3 values is unique.
We also have a table called T_Lookup. tID in table T is a foreign key relating to T_Lookup which has a column Type where one possible value is "Approved".
Here's what I need to do: I need to select some INV columns and the earliest date in table T where the tID represents an "Approved" Type in T_Lookup and the sID is the one that corresponds to the INV row in question.
I hope that makes sense. The final query will be something like
SELECT Aa, Bb, Cc, Date
FROM INV
LEFT JOIN (
              -- some convoluted thing that ultimately just needs 
              -- Date plus an inventory ID for the join
          ) S ON INV.ID = S.InventoryId

It's the ordering of things in SQL that is making this difficult for me. It's a lot easier to just conceptualize this: "From the T table, for each sID that has SomeOtherColumn = 1 and bID = MyID in the B table, get the Date of the earliest 'Approved' T and attach that to the details of the INV object corresponding to that sID."
Things to note:

Yes, every sID will have at least one 'Approved' T. There may be more than one, but remember that the combination of sID + tID + Date will be unique, which means there will only be one "earliest Approved T" for that sID. [Edited to add: It is not possible for there to be 2 'Approved' Ts on the same date.]
Remember that sID having SomeOtherColumn = 1 and bID = MyID in the B table is how we get to a one-to-one relationship between an sID and an INV.ID, so despite how convoluted this sounds, yes, there will always be exactly one Date per INV.ID once we get this query working. (The S table has multiple sIDs for every INV.ID, which is why we have to reference the B table first to filter down the sIDs.)


You should add some example data using a text table format and what you tried so far as well as expected output. Sounds like you want a select * from INV i CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM someTables st WHERE st.ID = i.ID... ORDER BY date DESC) ca

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

You just apply your joins, exactly as you stated. You can resolve the "earliest" part of your problem with a cross apply or using row_number to order the results and take the first for each group (I think in this case the grouping is on the ID you are interested in).
Note: These examples are necessarily "pseudocode" rather than working solutions, because your question is not rich in detail.
Example (pseudocode) with row_number:
; with cte as (
select 
    inv.ID,
    t.[Date],
    row_number() over (
        partition by inv.ID
        order by t.[Date] desc) as SortOrder
from 
    dbo.INV inv
    inner join dbo.S s
    on s.sID = inv.ID
    inner join B b
    on b.sID = inv.ID
    and b.SomeOtherColumn = 1
    inner join dbo.T t
    on t.sID = inv.ID
    inner join dbo.T_Lookup tl
    on tl.tID = t.tID
    and tl.[Type] = 'Approved'
)
select * from cte where SortOrder = 1

Example (pseudocode) with cross apply:
select 
    inv.ID,
    t.[Date]
from 
    dbo.INV inv
    inner join dbo.S s
    on s.sID = inv.ID
    inner join B b
    on b.sID = inv.ID
    and b.SomeOtherColumn = 1
    inner join dbo.T t
    on t.sID = inv.ID
    cross apply (
        select top (1) tl.tID
        from dbo.T_Lookup tl
        where tl.tID = t.tID
        and tl.[Type] = 'Approved' 
        order by tl.[Date] desc
    ) ca


it is not 100% clear to me what you've asked but after reading your question a few times, I will give it a shot. Here is my take on what you might be looking for -
    SELECT Aa, Bb, Cc, Date
FROM INV
LEFT JOIN (
 --select the first result with the correct WHERE clause and ensure that you're ordering the results by Date in desc order
    SELECT TOP 1 sID FROM [table].[B] 
    INNER JOIN [table].[T] ON T.sID = B.sID
    INNER JOIN [table].[T_Lookup] ON T_Lookup.tID = T.tID 
    WHERE   B.bID = INV.MyID 
        AND B.SomeOtherColumn = 1           
        AND T_Lookup.Type = 'Approved'
    ORDER BY T.Date DESC
) S
ON INV.ID = S.InventoryId


Oh I thought this was wrong at first but you can use TOP (N) in a subquery so yes, this is another way! And I think yet another approach would use a MAX() on the date in the subquery.

you can't use LEFT JOIN likes that, because INV.MyID won't be available inside it, gotta go with OUTER APPLY
